# Unable to feed ListBox

Tags: listbox, ms-access-2010

Good morning all,

I'm trying to get a list box feeded by a key code on the main form. The list box is on a sub form.

I'm using the row source to create the link to the table, from where the list box is supposed to be feeded.[Row Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeTxp.jpg)

But for any reason, I can't get the List Box showing the details of the countries the user just created.

I've checked all the parameters, and all look good...[List Box properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hanFy.jpg)

I've also tested the query without the link to the main form, and it's working well. I have on the same sub-form another list box which uses the same query (more or less) and it's working well.

I tried everything I could, even on a new form, and I tested from scratch on a blank DB by copying all the items, and I got the same... a blank list box.

If anyone has a clue of what's wrong.

Thank you very much for any help,

Cheers

Hakeem

Comment: Open the "wor" form and use the Direct window (Ctrl+g) to check the parameter. Type `? Forms!wor!fnKeyCode` and Return. See if it gives an error or the selected value.

Comment: When I try this, it returns the right value. No error messages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found something that helped me. It's a kind of workaround, but I'm okay with this.

I just needed to requery the list after user changes the value of the Country field, using the listbox.requery command, after that all the countries appear.

I'm ok with that, probably it's how the list box is working.

I hope this will help some other people.

Thanks

Hakeem